# How to detect extension of image without extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave, rmagick

My situation:
I have application, based on RubyOnRails.
I use Carrierwave for images uploading.

I have many files saved without extensions mistakenly.
So, all of these have content_type with empty value

Is there a way to restore extensions for these images?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the unix command `file` to try and detect the MIME type. For example:

```
$ file -bi i_am_a_png
image/png; charset=binary
```

This attempts to determine the file type by it's signature (binary structure).

You could run a bash script like this to infer a file extension and rename files accordingly:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$"\n"
for f in *
do
  mime=`file -bi $f`
  if [ $? == 0 ]
  then
      ext=( $(echo $mime | awk -F ";" '{ gsub(".*/", ""); print $1}') )
      cmd="mv $f $f.$ext"

      echo $cmd
      # `$cmd`    # Uncomment when you're happy with the command output
  else
      echo "Could not detect file type"
  fi
done
```

It just loops through the files in the current directory, runs `file -bi` and grabs the section of the string that could pass for an extension ("png" in "image/png"). It then renames the file with the extension. By default it just prints out the command, so uncomment that if you're happy it's doing the right thing.

Comment: On macOS I needed `file -bI <filename>` to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to infer it from the file signatures: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
require 'RMagick'
puts Magick::Image::read(filename).first.format
```

Here's the [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/imageattrs.html#format) to the doc